# Shiro multiple principals must be unique

Tags: java, shiro

I am using [shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/) v1.2.2 for authentication in a web program. I have 2 principals for each user, a primary value and some other value and so I am using the [`SimplePrincipalCollection`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/SimplePrincipalCollection.html) to store these 2 principals.

The problem I am having is that if the 2 principals are the same value (although they represent 2 distinct concepts in my system), the `SimplePrincipalCollection` only stores 1 value and so calls to `SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipals()` only has 1 value.

My realm [`doGetAuthenticationInfo`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthenticatingRealm.html#doGetAuthenticationInfo) implementation looks something like this:

```
@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authcToken) throws AuthenticationException {
    ...
    List<Integer> principalList = new ArrayList<>();
    principalList.add(primaryPrincipal); // This is the primary principal so should be first in the list
    principalList.add(secondaryPrincipal);

    PrincipalCollection principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(principalList, getName());
    AuthenticationInfo authInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(principals, credentials);
    return authInfo;
}
```

So if `primaryPrincipal` and `secondaryPrincipal` are the same value, the `SimplePrincipalCollection` only stores 1 value. I have verified this with a simple test:

```
@Test
public void testMultiplePrincipal() {
    final String realmName = "TestRealm";

    List<Integer> principalList = new ArrayList<>();
    principalList.add(1);
    principalList.add(2);

    PrincipalCollection principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(principalList, realmName);
    assertThat((List<?>) principals.asList(), hasSize(2)); // This passes

    principalList = new ArrayList<>();
    principalList.add(1);
    principalList.add(1);

    principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(principalList, realmName);
    assertThat((List<?>) principals.asList(), hasSize(2)); // This fails because size = 1
}
```

Upon debugging, I found that this behaviour is caused by `SimplePrincipalCollection` using a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to store the principals.

I know that I can define my own custom principal object and use the constructor [`SimpleAuthenticationInfo(Object principal, Object credentials, String realmName)`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/SimpleAuthenticationInfo.html#SimpleAuthenticationInfo) but then I would have to change the code that calls `SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal()`.

Am I using the `SimplePrincipalCollection` the wrong way and is there a way I can get around this unique principal problem without defining a custom principal?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are using the principals?  Are they simple strings?  Also, instead of getting a single principal, you could get the principal collection from your subject, and use a more [specific method](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/PrincipalCollection.html) to get the principal you are looking for.

Comment: Just to confirm: you have two principals of the same value **in the same realm** that represent different concepts in your domain?

Comment: @greenSocksRock Yes

Comment: @BrianDemers The principals are both integers. I am using the principal collection, but the collection only gives me 1 value even though I construct it with 2. That's what my problem is.

Comment: @user2718281 I understand now.  The principal's are stored in a map based as a `Set`.  The principals of a subject _should_ be unique.  You may be better off creating your own object to represent your principal, backed a bean (or other object).